# Polynomial problem with vieta formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was working on an algebra problem set and I came across this question:
let
$$
P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{20} a_i x^i.
$$
Where $a_{20}=1$ and $a_0=1$ and all coefficients are real numbers. The roots of this polynomial are
$$
-r_{10}, -r_9, \ldots, -r_1, r_1, r_2,\ldots,r_9, r_{10},
$$ where all $r_j$ are positive reals.

**Question**. Show that $a_2 \cdot a_{18}>100$

I tried using Vieta's formulas but I wasn't really getting anywhere. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is false, take all the roots arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: It should also be given that $a_0=1$

Comment: Yeah thanks, I forgot about that. Added it in though.

Comment: Please do not vandalize the question after receiving answers.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $a_0=1$

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_{20}$ be the roots of $P(x)=0$

$\Rightarrow\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_{20}=0$

Also, $\frac{1}{\alpha_1}+\frac{1}{\alpha_2}+...\frac{1}{\alpha_{20}}=0$

$$a_{18}=\sum (\alpha_i)(\alpha_j)=\frac{(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_{20})^2-\alpha_1^2-\alpha_2^2-...-\alpha_{20}^2}{2}=\frac{-\alpha_1^2-\alpha_2^2-...-\alpha_{20}^2}{2}$$

Replacing $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ in $P(x)$ we get an equation whose roots are $\frac{1}{\alpha_1},\frac{1}{\alpha_2},...,\frac{1}{\alpha_{20}}$

So, $$a_2=\sum\frac{1}{\alpha_i \alpha_j}=\frac{(\alpha_1^{-1}+\alpha_2^{-1}+...\alpha_{20}^{-1})^{2}-\alpha_1^{-2}-\alpha_2^{-2}-...-\alpha_{20}^{-2}}{2}=\frac{-\alpha_1^{-2}-\alpha_2^{-2}-...-\alpha_{20}^{-2}}{2}$$

$$a_2a_{18}=\left(\frac{-\alpha_1^2-\alpha_2^2-...-\alpha_{20}^2}{2}\right)\left(\frac{-\alpha_1^{-2}-\alpha_2^{-2}-...-\alpha_{20}^{-2}}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2-...+\alpha_{20}^2}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\alpha_1^{-2}+\alpha_2^{-2}+...+\alpha_{20}^{-2}}{2}\right)$$

$a_2a_{18}=\left(r_1^2+r_2^2-...+r_{10}^2\right)\left(r_1^{-2}+r_2^{-2}+...+r_{10}^{-2}\right)\geq 100$

(Using the inequality $A.M\geq H.M$)

If $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ be positive real numbers then $A.M\geq H.M$

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}\geq \frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last step? (Using AM-HM to prove the product is greater than 100)

Comment: @Cherry . I have edited. Does this meet your requirement.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. coefficient of $x^{18}$ is sum of product of roots taken two at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P(x)$ be the given polynomial of degree $20$. Note the roots (of $P$) are all of the form $\{s, -s\}$. It follows that $P$ is a even polynomial, or in other words $a_{19}=a_{17}=a_{15}=\cdots=a_1=0$.

Let $H$ be the set $\{r_1,-r_1, r_2, -r_2, \cdots, r_{10}, -r_{10}\}$. From Vieta's formulae, $a_{18}$ should be the product of roots, each term (taken from $H$) two at a time, that is $r_{1}(r_2+r_3+\cdots+r_{10}-r_1-r_2+\cdots -r_{10})+r_2(r_1+r_3+\cdots+r_{10}-r_1-r_2+\cdots -r_{10})+\cdots$. Hence $a_{18}=-r_{1}^2-r_{2}^2+\cdots-r_{10}^2$. Note that $1=a_{20}=a_{0}$ means $r_1^2r_2^2 \cdots r_{10}^2=1$. As all the roots are positive (that is $r_i>0$) we see $r_1 r_2 \cdots r_{10}=1$.

And similarly $a_2$ is $r_1(r_2r_3\cdots r_{10}(-r_1)(-r_2)\cdots (-r_{9}))+r_1(r_2r_3\cdots r_{10}(-r_2)\cdots (-r_{9})(-r_{10}))+r_1(r_2r_3\cdots r_{10}(-r_1)(-r_2)\cdots(-r_{8})(-r_{10}))+\cdots$.

Hence $a_2$ is $[-(\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{r_{10}})+(\frac{1}{r_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{r_{10}})]+\cdots$. The dots in the previous sentence come from the terms created by the roots $r_2, r_3$ and so on. Hence $a_2=-\frac{1}{r_1}-\frac{1}{r_2}+\cdots -\frac{1}{r_{10}}$.

So $a_2 \times a_{18}=(\frac{1}{r_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{r_{10}})(r_{1}^2+r_{2}^2+\cdots+r_{10}^2)$.

Applying the AM-GM inequality, to $\sum_{1 \le i \le 10}r_i^2$, we see $(r_{1}^2+r_{2}^2+\cdots+r_{10}^2) \ge 10$ and again applying the AM-GM inequality to $\frac{1}{r_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{r_{10}}$, we note $\frac{1}{r_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{r_{10}} \ge 10$. This gives the desired result.